# What would be the easiest way to get the runtime type with the generic arguments reset?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

```
let t = typeof<HashSet<Dictionary<int, string>>>
t.Assembly.GetType(t.Namespace + "." + t.Name)
```

By that I mean something equivalent to the above, but without having to traverse the `Assembly` to find the original type. `Mono.Cecil` has `Resolve` for this I think, but I am not sure how to do it with the standard reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx)